# QStandardItem missing __hash__ method

Tags: python, qt, hash, pyqt, qstandarditem

I found when converting some Python2/Qt4 code to Python3/Qt5, that apparently QStandardItem can no longer be used as a dict key in as it doesn't have `__hash__` implemented, and therefore is not considered immutable anymore.

Those two snippets show the issue:

**PyQt4:**

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> a = QtGui.QStandardItem()
>>> b = {}
>>> b[a] = "1"
>>> a.__hash__()
2100390
```

**PyQt5:**

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtGui
>>> a = QtGui.QStandardItem()
>>> b = {}
>>> b[a] = "1"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'QStandardItem'
>>> a.__hash__()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why was the change done? Should I not use QStandardItem as a dict key?

The obvious workaround would be to subclass QStandardItem and reimplement a trivial version of `__hash__` (which I've done). But is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe a question for the [mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt, there are three [requirements for hashability](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#the-qhash-hashing-function):

1. the type must be an assignable data type
2. the type must define an `==` operator
3. a `qHash` function must be defined for the type

So if PyQt wants to maintain consistency with Qt, it should only define `__hash__` when the above conditions apply, and its implementation of it should simply delegate to whatever `qHash` function Qt provides.

The behaviour when using Python 2 with PyQt4/5 should probably be considered a misfeature, because the results it gives are *not* consistent with Qt. This can be seen by looking at what happens with a type that **is** hashable (in Qt terms):

Using Python 3:

```
>>> a = QtCore.QUrl('foo.bar')
>>> b = QtCore.QUrl('foo.bar')
>>> a == b
True
>>> hash(a) == hash(b)
True
```

This is exactly what we want: objects that *compare* equal, should also *hash* equal. But now look at what happens when using the same version of PyQt with Python 2:

```
>>> a = Qt.QUrl('foo.bar')
>>> b = Qt.QUrl('foo.bar')
>>> a == b
True
>>> hash(a) == hash(b)
False
```

It seems that something like the object's *identity* is used by the `__hash__` implementation in Python 2, which obviously won't ever be consistent with Qt's hashing semantics.

The `QStandardItem` class has *never* been hashable in Qt, so for the sake of consistency, PyQt now chooses not to provide a `__hash__` method for it. And since instances of `QStandardItem` are, in fact, mutable, PyQt quite reasonably leaves it up to the user to decide when to define `__hash__`, and how to implement it. For compatibility with Python 2, this could probably just return `id(self)`.