# PyQt5 QStandardItem enumeration error - unhashable type: 'QStandardItem'

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm enumerating `valuesUnique` object which is `QtGui.QStandardItemModel` object with:

```
for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):
    action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
    self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)
    action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
    self.menuValues.addAction(action)
```

Where `valuesUnique` is generated from model:

```
valuesUnique = [self.model.item(row, self.logicalIndex)
                        for row in range(self.model.rowCount())
                        ]
```

And model is created from

```
class PandasTableModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
...
```

from pandas DataFrame.

Error i get:

> unhashable type: 'QStandardItem'

How can I fix enumeration part?

Comment: The problem is with creating a `set` from a collection of `QStandardItem`s. Besides that, `QAction` expects a string as an input parameter, not a `QStandardItem` when initializing an instance. Did you perhaps mean `valuesUnique = [self.model.item(row, self.logicalIndex).text() for row in range(self.model.rowCount())]`?

Comment: @Heike . Works! :) Great, thank you! Can you formulate that in answer so I can accept it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749631/qstandarditem-missing-hash-method is not answer to this question. Answer is in the comment of @Heike